# Multiterm background color is wrong

Tags: emacs, terminal

I added multi-term to my emacs config. It works great, but any text in console and some whitespaces (including these in vim from ssh) have white background and since I use deeper-blue style with dark background it does not look nice. How to fix this?

Here is screen: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rh1q9v&s=6

Comment: It is likely to be a problem in your prompts PS1 variables, usually defined in `.profile` or `.bashrc`. And probably not an Emacs issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors in term.el does not work well sometimes, depending on the timing it is loaded.  Calling this after setting your color theme may solve the problem.

```
(setq term-default-fg-color (face-foreground 'default))
(setq term-default-bg-color (face-background 'default))
```